# how to filter google-map-markers using angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

```js
.controller('MapCtrl', [
        '$scope', '$http', '$location', '$window', '$filter', '$ionicLoading', '$compile','$timeout','$ionicPopup',
        function($scope, $http, $location, $window, $filter, $ionicLoading, $compile, $timeout,$ionicPopup) {
 $scope.favoriteStore = '';
    $scope.Storetype = [{
        name: "Nokia"
    }, {
        name: "Samsung"
    }];
 $scope.submit =function()
 {
        if($scope.favoriteStore == 'Nokia') {
            alert($('#nokia').val());
        } else {
            alert($('#samsung').val());
        }
 
 
 }  
            $http.get('*****').success(function(data, dealers, response) {
                function initialize() {
                    var serverData = data;
                    $scope.locations = [];
                    for (var i = 0; i < serverData.length; i++) {
                var modal = [
                data[i].Store_Name, data[i].S_Location.Latitude, data[i].S_Location.Longitude, i, 'images/arrow.svg', data[i]._id,data[i].Store_Type,data[i].Services];
                $scope.locations.push(modal); 
            }
     var locations = [
                ['Sakthi Nokia Store', '12.901599', '77.594563', '1', 'images/arrow.svg.svg', '55a78953815356700bee698f','Nokia','Interior Services,Exterior Services,Regular Services & Maintenance'],
                ['Google Mobile Center', '12.9165534', '77.5474802', '2', 'images/arrow.svg.svg', '55a786d1815356700bee6982','Nokia,Samsung','Software problem & updates,Interior Services'],
    ['Zig zag mobiles', '12.9033434', '77.5574802', '3', 'images/arrow.svg.svg', '55a786d1815356700bee6982','Samsung','Hardware Problem,Interior Services,Exterior Services,Other Services'],
    ['Guptha mobile Corner', '12.9165534', '77.5456742', '4', 'images/arrow.svg.svg', '55a786d1815356700bee6982','Nokia,Samsung','Regular Services & Maintenance'],
    ];

                    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                        zoom: 13,
                        center: new google.maps.LatLng(12.9667, 77.5667),
                        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                    });



                    var marker, i;

                    for (i = 0; i < $scope.locations.length; i++) {

                        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            position: new google.maps.LatLng($scope.locations[i][1], $scope.locations[i][2]),
                            map: map,
                            icon: $scope.locations[i][4],
                            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,

                        });


                        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                            return function() {


                                var compiled = $compile('<div><div>' + $scope.locations[i][0] + ' </div><div>' + $scope.locations[i][1] + ' </div><div>' + $scope.locations[i][2] + ' </div><div><button ng-click="getid(locations[' + i + '][5])">Get</button></div></div>')($scope);

                                var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                                    content: compiled[0]
                                });


                                infowindow.open(map, marker);
                                $scope.$apply();

                            }

                        })(marker, i));
                    }
                    
                    $scope.getid = function(id) {
     console.log(id)
                        
                    }

                    
                    $scope.map = map;
                }

                
            });
   }
  
    ])
```

```html
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://fiddle.jshell.net/js/lib/dummy.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.2.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="https://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/dist/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/dist/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/docs/css/bootstrap-3.3.2.min.css">
<script type='text/javascript' src="https://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/docs/js/bootstrap-3.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.1/angular.js"></script>
<ion-content ng-controller="MapCtrl">
 <form data-ng-submit="submit()">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="store in Storetype">
            <label>{{store.name}}
                <input type="radio" name="storetype" ng-model="$parent.favoriteStore" value="{{store.name}}" />
            </label>
        </li>
    </ul>
 <div ng-show="favoriteStore == 'Nokia'" style="padding:20px">
    <select id="nokia" multiple="multiple">
      <option value="Interior Services">Interior Services</option>
      <option value="Exterior Services">Exterior Services</option>
      <option value="Regular Services & Maintenance">Regular Services & Maintenance</option>
      <option value="Software problem & updates">Software problem & updates</option>
      <option value="Hardware Problem">Hardware Problem</option>
    </select>
     <br /><br />
    <input type="submit" id="btnget" value="submit" />
</div>
<div ng-show="favoriteStore == 'Samsung'" style="padding:20px">
   <select id="samsung" multiple="multiple">
     <option value="Interior Services">Interior Services</option>
     <option value="Exterior Services">Exterior Services</option>
     <option value="Regular Services & Maintenance">Regular Services & Maintenance</option>
     <option value="Software problem & updates">Software problem & updates</option>
     <option value="Hardware Problem">Hardware Problem</option>
     <option value="Other Services">Other Services</option>
    </select>
    <br /><br />
   <input type="submit" id="btnget" value="Submit" />
</div>
</form>
  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  <div id="map" data-tap-disabled="true"></div>
  </ion-content>
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[

$(function() {
  $('#nokia').multiselect({
    includeSelectAllOption: true
  });
  
  $('#samsung').multiselect({
    includeSelectAllOption: true
  });
});

</script>
```

I have enclosed my code. I have four stores it's showing properly in google map but I want to filter google map markers based on selection.here I have store type and their services, I need to filter based on these two. I have two radio buttons which is nokia and samsung .depends on radio button selection services coming after submit the button I need to filter the map-markers. Example:

case 1:In radio Button User selected Nokia and in that services list user has checked Interior Services and submitted.here Nokia i need to check with data[i].Store_Type and Interior Services i need to check with data[i].Services

answer for this case it should display only two markers 1.Sakthi Nokia Store,2.Google Mobile Center

case2:In radio Button User selected Nokia and in that services list user has checked Interior Services,Regular Services & Maintenance and submitted.here Nokia i need to check with data[i].Store_Type and Interior Services,Regular Services & Maintenance i need to check with data[i].Services

answer for this case it should display only two markers 1.Sakthi Nokia Store,2.Google Mobile Center3.Guptha mobile Corner

case 3:In radio Button User selected Samsung and in that services list user has checked Interior Services and submitted.here Samsung i need to check with data[i].Store_Type and Interior Services i need to check with data[i].Services

answer for this case it should display only two markers 1.Google Mobile Center 2.Zig zag mobiles please some one help me out i'm new to this google map api and angularjs.

Answer (score 0):

I have an answer, but it's pure js, you can filter the markers through the radio buttons.

I answered this in the Russian portal [here](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/876311/192907).

**Google Translate:**

The markers are divided into groups in the myMarkers object, each key is the name of the group, and each value is the group object in which the keys are the marker headers, and the value is the marker coordinates.

In each group there can be options, in options you can set any parameters that will be applied to each group marker, in this example there are icons and animations in the options.

The googleMarkers object is structured like myMarkers, but it contains the Google markers objects, and not their description, this object is populated in the setMarkers function.

Radio buttons are tied to groups by the data- * attribute, this allows you to use an arbitrary id for the element. Initially, those markers that relate to the radio button that is checked are displayed. A radio button with data-marker = "showall" shows all the elements.

The rest should be understandable, there are comments in the code and ES2015 is used.

```js
let map, googleMarkers = {} // карта и объект содержащий объекты гугл маркеров
const radios = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio][data-marker]')
const myMarkers = { // описание маркеров
  first: {
    'Title 1': [52.4357808, 4.991315699999973],
  },
  second: { // имя группы
    options: { // опции для маркеров этой группы
      icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png' 
    }, 
    'Title 2': [52.4357808, 4.981315699999973],
    'Title 3': [52.4555687, 5.039231599999994],
  },
  third: {
    options: { 
      icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue-dot.png',
      animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE
    },
    'Title 4': [52.4755687, 5.019261599999994],
    'Title 5': [52.4555687, 5.049231599999994],
    'Title 6': [52.4055687, 5.039236599999994]
  }
}

initMap()
// для каждой радио-кнопки добавляет слушатель события клика
radios.forEach(i => i.addEventListener('click', radioClick))


function initMap() {
  const center = new google.maps.LatLng(52.4527808, 4.991315699999973)
  const mapOptions = {
    zoom: 11,
    center,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
  }

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions)
  setMarkers(map)
}

function setMarkers (map) {
  let isFirst = true
  for (let group in myMarkers) {
    for (let title in myMarkers[group]) {
      if (title === 'options') // не берет во внимание опции
        continue
   
      const myMarker = myMarkers[group][title]
      const visible = document.querySelector(`input[type=radio][data-marker=${group}]`).checked
      const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        title,
        position: {lat: myMarker[0], lng: myMarker[1]},
        map,
        visible,
        ...myMarkers[group].options // берет опции группы
      })
      
      googleMarkers[group] = googleMarkers[group] || [] // создает массив если его нет
      googleMarkers[group].push(marker)
    }
  }
}

function radioClick ({ target }) { // берет target события
  const group = target.dataset.marker // id группы к которой принадлежит радио-кнопка
  const arrOfEveryGroup = Object.values(googleMarkers) // массив массивов групп маркеров
  const everyMarker = [].concat.apply([], arrOfEveryGroup) // массив всех маркеров
  
  if (group === 'showall') {
    // показывает всех
    everyMarker.forEach(i => i.setVisible(true))
    return
  }
  // те кто был видимым становиться не видемым
  everyMarker.forEach(i => i.visible && i.setVisible(false))
  
  // показывает группу к которой принадлежит радио-кнопка
  for (let marker of googleMarkers[group])
    marker.setVisible(!marker.visible)
}
```

```css
#map-canvas { 
  height: 160px;
  width: 100%;
}
#map-canvas img {
  max-width: none;
}
    
#map-canvas div {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>


<div id="map-canvas" ></div>


<input data-marker="first" id="first" type="radio" name="myMarkers">
<label for="first">First</label>

<input data-marker="second" id="second" type="radio" name="myMarkers" checked>
<label for="second">second</label>

<input data-marker="third" id="third" type="radio" name="myMarkers">
<label for="third">third</label>

<input data-marker="showall" id="showall" type="radio" name="myMarkers">
<label for="showall">Show all</label>
```